# responsive design in mobile iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, safari

I would love some help with this... I have a website set up to be responsive and it works in all browsers and mobile devices EXCEPT some newer mobile Safari browsers. I have tried this on iPads and a iPhone 4, as well as Android tablets and phones, and it only shows up on some iPhones 5&6. The viewport is set: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/> and content is set to width: 100%; in a div. You can see a screen shot of the result here: http://davewhitemultimedia.com/images/mobile_iOS_issue.png . I have tried setting the scale-1.1, etc., using a javascript to a different page, where I set the width to 580px but the same thing happened.  Unfortunately, i don't own a device that does this, so I've been going to the local Verizon store to check different things to see if they are a fix, but it is really awkward, and I am not entirely sure I was not looking at a cached version some of the times.

You can see the page at http://grandcentremassage.net . Again, unless it is Safari on some iPhones, you may not see the problem. Thank you in advance to anyone who knows what the problem is and has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer I found works and is too easy, It's adding "shrink-to-fit=no" to the viewport meta tag. I recommend this for responsive page design: